# When a div doesn't contain text it repositions

Tags: css, html, position

I am trying to make a 'About me' website. I have 3 sections each filling 100% screenheight and width.

Each section is a `div` and inside that `div`, there are several other `div`s and a couple of pictures.

The `div`(section1) that is a direct child of `body` is only containing a single "." and other divs. (The single "." will be explained)

My probem is that if I delete the "." the whole page moves a couple of hundred pixels down.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cb3Zr/

Try deleting the "." from `<div id="section1" class="section">.`
.

The html and css is written in NetBeans IDE 7.3.1 and  I use 'Run project' to view to page in chrome (Version 31.0.1650.63 m).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just wrote [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20935585/1729885) - applies verbatim to your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `overflow:auto;` to your `#section1`